# Protractor-Failed Timed out waiting

Tags: protractor

Currently I am  having an  issue on this  e2e Automation  tool  (protractor)  I tried to set a wait element option but  I am still getting the following error on it.

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 12 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>       While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, #company-code). 
>       The following tasks were pending:
>        - $timeout: function u(){return e.isActivatePage?void t.cancel(s):(s=t(u,o),void i.poll(r).then(function(t){d=t,e.$broadcast("noti-count-updated",d)}))}

Appreciate your comments on solving this. The codeI tried for an negative scenario as follows, Thanks

```
it('After invalid login it should show an error toast', function () {
    browser.get('https:XXXX.com');
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#company-code')))
        .then(function () {
            browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('company-code')).sendKeys('ccXXX');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('email@domain.com');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('wrong password');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('signin')).click()

                .then(function () {

                    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('.alert-warning')))
                        .then(function () {

                            var myElement = element(by.css('.alert-warning'));
                            expect(myElement.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

                        });
                });
        });
});
```

});

Comment: Does your app having any kind of polling which is using $timeout. This may cause the error, try instead with $interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` will execute only after `EC.visibilityOf($('#company-code')`. But it should be set up before your test it starts.

You should write `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` in you `protractor.conf.js` file in `onPrepare() { }` block.

If you want to try it in one test you should `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` as the first line in you `it()` block. Or you could set it in `beforeAll()`.

Again, I prefer to keep it inside configuration file in the `onPrepare() { }`

Comment: Appreciate your comments on this, I have tried this all-ready, and just browser restart  command worked well, by the way do you know how to track an element by an ng model name?

Comment: You are welcome. Could you mark my answer as right? For your next question better to create new one post.

Comment: @olesk note,  i tried to  vote but system is not allowing to vote, might redo the same when i get more points..

Answer (score -1):

You should add below configuration into conf.js file to resolve the time out issue.

```
exports.config = {

allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

//Also add jasmine node options.

jasmineNodeOpts: {

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,


},
```

};

I think above solution will help this.

Comment: it will not help at all, because you just set timeout instead of resolve author's problem

Comment: Hi Akash,Thanks for the pointing this tip,how ever I have already tried   the following parameters 120,000 and 60,000   rather than above   but the issue exists  yet..

Comment: @akash Sure thanks for posting , I have used this also, I had to create some additional  commands to run the test also..